# Can't access a parameter within this function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an issue with the param `timesheet` which is an object. I can access it in the comment area:

```
"// Can access timesheet here"
```

but not:

```
"// Can't access timesheet here"
```

Code:

```
function d(obj, timesheet){
var newDate;
var timesheetParams = {
    weekNumber: moment().week(),
    year: moment().year(), 
    employee: obj.employee
};

Timesheet.create(timesheetParams, function(err, newTimesheet) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Test: " + JSON.stringify(timesheet));
        for(var num = 0; num <= 6; num++){
                // sets the date from the start of the week.
            newDate = moment().startOf('week').weekday(num).toDate();

            // Can access timesheet here
            console.log(timesheet.timesheet.start[1]);

            if(timesheet.timesheet.start[num] === ''){
                Times.create(timesheet.timesheet, function(err, newTimes, timesheet) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err); 
                    } else {
                        newTimes.timesheet.id = newTimesheet.id;
                        newTimes.date = newDate;
                        newTimes.start = "OFF";
                        newTimes.end = "OFF";
                        newTimes.save();
                        newTimesheet.times.push(newTimes);
                        newTimesheet.save();
                    }
                });

            } else { 
                // Can't access timesheet here
                console.log("Kieran : " + timesheet.timesheet.start[0]);
                Times.create(timesheet, function(err, newTimes, timesheet) {
                    console.log("Kieran : " + timesheet.start[0]);
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err); 
                    } else {
                        newTimes.timesheet.id = newTimesheet.id;
                        newTimes.date = newDate;
                        console.log("Day Printed: " + timesheet);
                        newTimes.start = timesheet.timesheet.start[num];
                        newTimes.end = timesheet.timesheet.end[num];
                        newTimes.save();
                        console.log("With numbers being put in: " + JSON.stringify(newTimes))
                        console.log("TESTER TIMES WITH NUMBERS: " + newTimes.times);
                        newTimesheet.times.push(newTimes);
                        newTimesheet.save();
                    }

                }); 
            }


            //console.log("TESTER TIMES: " + newTimesheet.times[num].start[num]);
        }
    }
});
}
```

I've tried everything to access it within the `if/else` but can't seem to access it. Keeps saying its undefined ><.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after this:

```
// Can't access timesheet here
console.log("Kieran : " + timesheet.timesheet.start[0]);
Times.create(timesheet, function (err, newTimes, timesheet) {
    ...
```

**timesheet** will be whatever the *Times.create()* function passes to the callback function (the anonymous function you're declaring with *function (err, newTimes, timesheet) {*

If your *console.log("Kieran : " + timesheet.timesheet.start[0]);* is logging **undefined**, then that won't be the issue. The only other difference I see is that in the section where you can access **timesheet**, you have:

```
console.log(timesheet.timesheet.start[1]);
```

Whereas where you can't you have:

```
console.log("Kieran : " + timesheet.timesheet.start[0]);
```

Which means maybe **.start[1]** is defined, but **.start[0]** is undefined.

(It is kind of hard to follow the code. It helps if you strip out the stuff unrelated to your question, like assigning values to the the newTimes properties.)

Comment: I found out what the issue was in the end. But you helped in making me see it clearer so will tick your answer :) Thank you!